# RCTBridge is Always Nil

Tags: ios, react-native

I have been using React Native for a mobile app project for over a year now. I have a native component to bridge the BLE stack to the React Native portion of the app. Recently I upgraded to version 9.1 of XCode and I cannot get the React-Native Bridge to work within the iOS version. The RCTBridge is always `nil` so I can never use the `eventDispatcher()`. Here is my setup:

I have a native Swift component which I integrate into the app via a bridgin header. The origanization looks like this:

```
BLEScanner.swift (This is the native component)
BluetoothModuleBridge.m
Module-Practive-Bridging-Header.h (The bridging header)
```

Relevant code snippets from each file:

**BLEScanner.swift**

```
import Foundation

@objc(BLEScanner)
class BLEScanner: NSObject {

  //....

  var bridge: RCTBridge!  // THIS IS ALWAYS NIL

  //....

  @objc func requestBluetoothState() -> Void {
    print("REQUEST BLE STATE")
    let ret = [
      "enabled" : true
    ]

    //THIS LINE WILL FAIL BECAUSE bridge IS NIL
    self.bridge.eventDispatcher().sendDeviceEvent(withName: "BluetoothStateEvent", body: ret)
  }

}
```

**BluetoothModuleBridge.m**

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>


@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(BLEScanner, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(requestBluetoothState)

@end
```

**Module-Practive-Bridging-Header.h**

```
// BluetoothModule-Bridging-Header.h
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>

#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "BugsnagReactNative/BugsnagReactNative.h"

#import "nokeLockSDK.h"
#import "nokeServerSDK.h"
#import "TI_aes_128.h"
```

**What I have Tried**

- Updated React Native from 0.36 to 0.50.3
- Tried running on multiple devices
- Tried on older version of XCode
- Tried compiling on different machine
- Compared to a similar app that works and uses this same design.

I am very confused as to why the `RCTBridge` is returning as nil. It seems odd to me that an XCode update would cause this, however, it is the only change made.

Can anyone point me in the right direction in debugging this issue?

I am using XCode 9.1 and React Native 0.50.3

Comment: What part of your code is responsible for setting the `BLEScanner.bridge` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your own initial method? If so try remove it. After my test, it has no problem.

And it is recommended to `Subclass RCTEventEmitter instead`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Are you referring to the BLEScanner class?

Comment: I have tested with the BLEScanner, it also worked. But I think  
Subclassing RCTEventEmitter is the best

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to subclass `RCTEventEmitter`. Just add the `@objc` attribute. So the variable should be `@objc var bridge: RCTBridge!`

Comment: Great !! Just adding @objc attribute, nil issue gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded to 9.1 and also React Native to 50.x from 30.x at the same time, you could have wrong imports, as that is something that changed around version 40.

It should be

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

Comment: Oops it looks like I forgot to update the code snippets after the upgrade. The code snippets should have the correct imports now.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to subclass `RCTEventEmitter`, implement protocol `RCTBridgeModule` in your `BLEScanner`.

That will solve the problem.